# printing from list using bluetooth printer in android

Tags: android, printing, android-bluetooth

this is my coding, i want to print from listview. so please tell me how to print.
if you have code using listview printing using sqlitedatabase, please tell me the solution

```
final myDBClass myDb = new myDBClass(this);
final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> SavedData = myDb.SelectAllCTRNSDATAforSaved();

listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

// List for chit collection
final SimpleAdapter sAdap;
sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(EODReport.this, SavedData,       R.layout.column_today_collectedlist,
new String[] {"FC_GR", "FC_TN", "FC_AMR", "CT_NAME"}, new int[] {R.id.fc_group,   R.id.fc_tn, R.id.fc_amr, R.id.fc_name});     
listView1.setAdapter(sAdap);

private void senddatatodevice() {  
try {  
mbtOutputStream = mbtSocket.getOutputStream();  
switch (mPrintType) {  
case 0:  
byte[] Command = { (byte) 0x09, FontStyleVal };  
mbtOutputStream.write(Command);


byte[] send = line.getBytes();  
mbtOutputStream.write(send);  
mbtOutputStream.write(0x0D);
mbtOutputStream.flush();  
break; 
default:  
break;  
}  
// outstream.write(0);  
// mbtOutputStream.close();  
// mbtOutputStream.flush();  
} catch (IOException e) {  
e.printStackTrace();  
}  
}
```